# grep not matching first part of line?

Tags: git, grep

When listing the branches in my repo I have...

```
01:23:36 Sun Dec 20 [ehime@localhost: +1] ~/Repositories
$ git branch -a
* (HEAD detached at origin/qastg)
  demo
  devel
  master
  mheprod
  pqa
  pre
  prod
  qalv
  qastg
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/development
  remotes/origin/demo
  remotes/origin/development
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/mheprod
  remotes/origin/pci
  remotes/origin/pcipqa
  remotes/origin/pqa
  remotes/origin/predevelopment
  remotes/origin/qalv
  remotes/origin/qastg
```

But running grep with `^` does not match as expected? Did I miss something?

```
01:23:39 Sun Dec 20 [ehime@localhost: +1] ~/Repositories
$ git branch -a |grep ^demo
```

Expected output `demo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant line does not start with `demo` - it has two whitespaces before it, so you have to address it. Consider, e.g.,:

```
$ git branch -a | grep '^  demo'
```

Or, if you want to be more generic:

```
$ git branch -a | grep '^\s*demo'
```

Comment: plus one and accepted, i didn't realize there was whitespace there. I should have known better ;)

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by Mureinik is completely fine.

For completeness, let's use `awk`: since it kind of slurps the leading spaces from the fields, it is enough to check if the first field starts with `demo`:

```
...something... | awk '$1 ~ /^demo/'
```

Storing your data in a file, I test it and it produces the desired output:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /^demo/' file
  demo
```

Comment: Great solution after the fact, plus one to you

Answer (score 0):

The `demo` is not at the beginning of the line.

Try `... | grep "^[ ]*demo"`.